# I hope I will be able to meet you one day and see you in real, that will be the best day of my life?

Tags: grammar

> See you in real, that will be the best day of my life.

Should it be "for real" instead of "in real"?

Comment: An alternative which fits in your question title is "in person": _I hope I will be able to meet you one day and see you __in person__, that will be the best day of my life?_

Comment: Yes, see you for real. Slangish.

Answer (score 2):

"In real" is definitely wrong here. "Real" is an adjective and needs to apply to a noun, but there is no such noun in your sentence.

Possible alternatives:

- "For real". This implies that whatever kind of meeting you have been doing up to now was not "real". It's an idiom that doesn't require a noun. If you were meeting virtually or by email etc. but don't consider that "really" meeting, it would work, but most people probably wouldn't use it.
- "In real life". This contrasts with virtual meetings, which might be real but not in real life.
- "In reality". Very similar to "In real life" and especially as an opposite of virtual meetings.
- "In person" This is a frequently used opposite of "virtual" when it comes to meetings. Probably the clearest.

There are plenty of other ways of saying this.

Comment: Thanks, I later got known that there should be "for real" when I writed the message.

Answer (score -1):

***For real*** would not apply here. It means

> INFORMAL
>  used to assert that something is genuine or is actually the
> case.
>
> - I'm not playing games—this is for real! ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=for%20real%20meaning&biw=1536&bih=664&sxsrf=ALiCzsaIJbl6lUyokjd8VfAtL1cGqKXnfQ%3A1661675494718&ei=5icLY56yK6WZhbIPtO2BoAg&ved=0ahUKEwieveDMj-n5AhWlTEEAHbR2AIQQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=for%20real%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAc6BggAEAoQQzoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoECAAQQzoECAAQDUoECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWNwMYOkPaABwAXgAgAGwAYgBtgmSAQMwLjmYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz))

Your sentence refers to seeing someone face to face, as opposed to seeing someone on a screen, or communicating with that someone through some sort of writing. So ***in real*** may be shortened from ***in real life***:

> A phrase used to indicate the existence or qualities of someone or something in reality, *specifically as opposed to online*.
>
> - We've been texting, and he seems nice enough, but I just don't know what he's like in real life. ([FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+real+life))

Comment: I think there should be "for real" as I didn't write "in real life".

Comment: @ArmaanVerma (a) please don't ask the community to proof-read song lyrics — which you may not be doing, but if you are, please don't; (b) your extract in a comment here doesn't feature "in real" as in the question. Please make sure that the question contains **all** information which **might possibly** be relevant, **including** the research you did yourself before asking.

Comment: Yes, I should not make song lyrics public.